# Associate custom CPT with another CPT's taxonomy and rewrite permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I am selling digital art ebooks with WooCommerce. I would like to provide a list of supplies with affiliate links for each one of these products.

Here is how I am organizing my CPT's:

```
Custom Post Type: product
    |
    - - > Product 1
    |
    - - > Product 2
    |
    - - > Product ...

Custom Post Type: supply
    |
    - - > Pen 1
    |
    - - > Pen 2
    |
    - - > Paper 1
    |
    - - > Paper 2
    |
    - - > ...
```

Each supply is part of a custom category:

```
Custom Taxonomy: supply_category
    |
    - - > Pens
    |       |
    |       - - > Pen 1
    |       |
    |       - - > Pen 2
    |       |
    |       - - > Pen ...
    |
    - - > Paper
    |       |
    |       - - > Paper 1
    |       |
    |       - - > Paper 2
    |       |
    |       - - > Paper ...
    |
    - - > ...
```

There are several supplies per category to provide our customers with options (price, availability, etc.).

Now, I want to associate my products with the supplies they need. To do so, I associated the `supply_category` taxonomy with the `product` CPT. That is, this taxonomy is shared by both the `supply` and the `product` CPT. Here is how the `product` CPT interacts with the taxonomy:

```
Product 1
    |
    - - belongs to - - > Pens
    |
    - - belongs to - - > Paper
    |
    - - belongs to - - > Any other supply type it may need
```

My goal is to display the list of supplies that the product requires upon checkout. That is, let's assume the customer purchased `Product 1`. I will then get all `supply_category` taxonomies associated with it, and then all supplies under each taxonomy. Add some rearranging and some CSS, and the user will just see a list of recommended supplies to purchase.

My question has to do with the permalinks. I have the following:

- `http://mysite/supplies/` Shows all `supply` CPTs.
- `http://mysite/supply_category/*` Shows all supplies and products under the taxonomy. I can remove the products and show only the supplies via the `pre_get_posts` filter.

How could I get something like `http://mysite/supplies/product-1` or `http://mysite/supply_category/pens/product-1`? My goal would be to provide a link to the supplies in the product description. Would it be a page template? Can the Rewrite API do this?

Is my data organization the best way to achieve what I want?

Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This post appears to be aimed towards generating opinion based answers. This is a forum aimed at solving problems, and I can't really see a problem defined within your post.

Comment: While I agree that some of my questions are asking for an opinion, I believe these opinions can be stated objectively (for example, in terms of efficiency), or with pros and cons (for example, a con of having a shared taxonomy for two post types is that the query for the taxonomy must be altered to only display one post type). Furthermore, at the end, I did ask a non-opinion question, which is how to achieve my rewrite of the URLs.